# Getting layer label from ArcMap Table Of Contents?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, layers, table-of-contents

How do I get a layer´s label from the TOC?

I can´t find a similar question and ArcGIS Help tells nothing about it.  I have searched even in other knowledge bases but with no success.

I need to get a layer´s label (not its description) to be able to work with it further.
[image]

Getting a layer´s name is easy but getting its label that appears in the TOC not.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, data_frame=df):
    layer_name = lyr.name
    layer_label = ????     # there is nothing like lyr.label
```

Comment: I would investigate the LegendElement class: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/legendelement-class.htm

Comment: https://community.esri.com/thread/70466

Comment: I had found these threads before I asked the question but unfortunately none of them is answering the question. The closest to the topic is one of them about setting `UniqueValuesSymbology (arcpy.mapping)` but it is still about _setting_, not about _retrieving_ the labels.

Comment: Well, I see that working with `UniqueValuesSymbology` is also about _retrieving_ layer´s labels, as explained by @Hornbydd in the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can access that text because you are using a *Single Symbol*. If you read the help file on layer objects in the arcpy mapping module a property of a layer is *symbologyType* which will return **OTHER** for single symbol and that is not a supported type.  If you were using *Unique Value*, a supported type, then you would be able to access those text with the following code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, data_frame=df):
    if lyr.name == "polys":
        # Found layer
        print(lyr.symbologyType)
        sym = lyr.symbology
        for l in sym.classLabels:
            print(l)
```

I strongly suspect you could access the text of a single symbol if you used ArcObjects but it is clear you are seeking a python solution.